# string regex pattern.replace(/\{0\}/, "$0.00") does not work

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Given that:

```
var pattern = "{0}";
```

Why does this not work:

```
pattern.replace(/\{0\}/g, "$0.00");
```

and yet:

```
pattern.replace("{0}", "$0.00");
```

the first results in: "{0}.00"
the second results in "$0.00"

meanwhile the following does work as expected (producing "$1.00"):

```
pattern.replace(/\{0\}/g, "$1.00");
```

Any tips or advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: don't use `{` use `(`

Comment: Actually both examples work fine in Chrome. Which browser are you testing with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a replacement string with regex, `$0` (and `$&`) represent the entire match. `$1` represents the first subpattern, and so on.

The appropriate workaround is to use `$$`, as this will be replaced with a literal `$`.

```
pattern.replace(/\{0\}/g,"$$0.00");
```

Comment: @Jerry This is ONLY true in regex replacements.